# Connecting to Azure SQL Data warehouse with active directory authentication using python from Ubuntu machine

Tags: sql-server, azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database, pyodbc, ubuntu-18.04

I am trying to connect to azure sql database with active directory authentication using pyodbc on an ubuntu machine. I installed all the required packages on the server (pyodbc, unixodbc etc) and also installed sql server 17 odbc driver.

My server is ubuntu 18.04, so only odbc sql server 17 drivers are supported. The connection wont work with odbc 13 drivers.

I use the below connection details:

```
import pyodbc
server = 'xxxx.database.windows.net'
database = 'xxxx'
username = 'xxx@xxx.org'
password = 'xxxxx'
driver= '{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}'
auth= 'ActiveDirectoryPassword'
conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER='+driver+';SERVER='+server+',1433;DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password+';Authentication=ActiveDirectoryPassword')
```

When I run the above connection details I face the below timeout error:

```
pyodbc.OperationalError: ('HYT00', '[HYT00] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

I even tried creating a connection string and using the below details but I still face the same issue.

```
pyodbc.connect(connection_string)
```

Am I missing any configurations? Please note that I tried this from a windows machine and was successful once I installed Microsoft Active Directory Authentication library for MS SQL Server and then by registering **adalsql.dll.**

Comment: Your python code is correct and it works ok in my environment.

Comment: Can you try to set "Connection Timeout=60" and test again?

Comment: Is your server Ubuntu 18.04? Also what were the configurations that you did for odbc 17 drivers, coz I didn't do any.

Comment: Yes,  my Ubuntu version is 18.04.2. I also use the ODBC 17 driver.

Comment: I tried with connection timeout as 30,60,120. Its not working. I am definitely missing some configuration.

Comment: Also, are you using active directory authentication to login to Azure DB/DW?

Comment: yes,of course. If you need, I can post my code for you. But I think it can not as the answer.

Comment: yes, please. can you post it.

Comment: Hi @roccmol09, I come back, please see the code in my answer.

Comment: Any news from this from a *nix machine? Thanks

Comment: None. The probable reason for Active directory authentication not working would be the use of Federation Sevice with Active directory.